# MacOS - Creating Symbolic Link for User Library from External HD to Primary HD

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, symbolic-link

I have a new 2018 Mac Mini. I use Macs a lot at work, but this is my first Mac for home use.

I have about 4TB of documents, data, photos and other media … far exceeding the 512GB SSD primary drive. So I purchased a large external drive, and used the “Advanced Options” when setting up my user account to create my home directory on the external drive.

This is working well, but there's a lot of chatter from the hard drive, especially at login, and I suspect it's due to accessing my Library folder. Is there any reason I shouldn't place my Library folder back on the SSD, and create a symbolic link to it from the external drive?

I expect this would work just fine in normal use, but I am concerned about special situations, such as when I upgrade to Catalina.

Comment: I changed the value of your data volume from 4GB to 4TB. I just assumed that this is a better fit related to your 512GB SSD that you mentioned to be too small. I hope that this was a good guess.

Comment: That was a good guess indeed.  Sorry for the trouble.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would work but if your profile indicates `~/Library` is on your external drive even if contents are linked to your internal SSD it will *still* have to check external drive every time it wants to access something in `~/Library` to resolve the link.

A more efficient solution would be to *move* your user folder (but not all the data obviously) back to your SSD and either link from SSD to external drive for non-Library folders or just access that data from the external drive.

You can set the path for your user back to default using :

`sudo dscl . create  /Users/yourUser NFSHomeDirectory /Users/yourUser`

This will apply next time you logon and create empty User folder hierarchy.

As the current contents of your Users folder will remain on the external drive you can either link to them from `/Users/yourUser` or use them where they are in `/Volumes/yourVolume/yourUser`.

If you want to copy existing contents of `~/Library` to your internal drive you could use *[rsync](https://ss64.com/osx/rsync.html)*.  For example :

`sudo rsync -aEv /Volumes/yourVolume/yourUser/Library /Users/yourUser`

Note it is necessary to [grant full disk access](http://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/) to terminal.app before doing so to avoid *"Operation not permitted"* errors.